# CS0103 The name 'SqliteEngine' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I'm trying to use `SqliteEngine` in the UWP C# project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using Microsoft.Data;

namespace SQLLite
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
    /// </summary>
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
        /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

            SqliteEngine.UseWinSqlite3();

            using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=PersonDB.db"))
            {
                db.Open();
                String table = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person(Primary_key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name NVARCHAR(50) NULL, LastName NVARCHAR(50) NULL)");
                SqliteCommand createTable = new SqliteCommand(table, db);
                try
                {
                    createTable.ExecuteReader();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

I installed those references:
[References Pic.][1]

It returns me the error "CS0103 The name 'SqliteEngine' does not exist in the current context".
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOV8k.png

Comment: .NET itself has no `SqliteEngine` class. Microsoft.Data.Sqlite has no such class either, it was [removed 6 years ago](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commit/d0710196a8a984cc2bb601f7b8dc1a43aebd0b90). Are you trying to use some old sample code? You should probably check the MSDN docs: [Use SQLite in a UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases)

Comment: @Clemens Yes UWP, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Panagiotis.

I found what was the issue.
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite had to be set on the 1.1.1 version.